# Unwanted md arrays created while creating SW RAID6 pool

Tags: raid, mdadm

I ran into issue where while i am creating bunch of RAID6 arrays on storage server, some unwanted random arrays were created with them for no reason.

I am using old disks but i ran mdadm --zero-superblock on all of them also with sgdisk -Z. Afer that mdadm --examine didnt find any array and after reboot there was also none. Disks were previously used in RAID50 arrangement.

Here is /proc/mdadm output. You can see md125..127 and completely random md23 that are for some reason created from still assembling new RAID6 array.

I would assume its possibly some old data from previous SW raid configuration, but as i said i wiped the disks and there was no trace of any arrays after that.

Why are they there and how can i get rid of them?

```
md9 : active raid6 sdbj[5] sdbi[4] sdbh[3] sdbg[2] sdbf[1] sdbe[0]
      11720540160 blocks super 1.2 level 6, 512k chunk, algorithm 2 [6/6] [UUUUUU]
      [>....................]  resync =  0.0% (387900/2930135040) finish=2139.9min speed=22817K/sec
      bitmap: 22/22 pages [88KB], 65536KB chunk

md125 : inactive md8[0](S)
      8790274048 blocks super 1.2

md8 : active raid6 sdbd[5] sdbc[4] sdbb[3] sdba[2] sdaz[1] sday[0]
      11720540160 blocks super 1.2 level 6, 512k chunk, algorithm 2 [6/6] [UUUUUU]
      [>....................]  resync =  0.0% (579836/2930135040) finish=2020.9min speed=24159K/sec
      bitmap: 22/22 pages [88KB], 65536KB chunk

md7 : active raid6 sdax[5] sdaw[4] sdav[3] sdau[2] sdat[1] sdas[0]
      11720540160 blocks super 1.2 level 6, 512k chunk, algorithm 2 [6/6] [UUUUUU]
      [>....................]  resync =  0.0% (759416/2930135040) finish=1735.8min speed=28126K/sec
      bitmap: 22/22 pages [88KB], 65536KB chunk

md6 : active raid6 sdar[5] sdaq[4] sdap[3] sdao[2] sdan[1] sdam[0]
      11720540160 blocks super 1.2 level 6, 512k chunk, algorithm 2 [6/6] [UUUUUU]
      [>....................]  resync =  0.0% (882816/2930135040) finish=1659.0min speed=29427K/sec
      bitmap: 22/22 pages [88KB], 65536KB chunk

md126 : inactive md5[1](S)
      8790274048 blocks super 1.2

md5 : active raid6 sdal[5] sdak[4] sdaj[3] sdai[2] sdah[1] sdag[0]
      11720540160 blocks super 1.2 level 6, 512k chunk, algorithm 2 [6/6] [UUUUUU]
      [>....................]  resync =  0.0% (1106488/2930135040) finish=1520.6min speed=32103K/sec
      bitmap: 22/22 pages [88KB], 65536KB chunk

md4 : active raid6 sdaf[5] sdae[4] sdad[3] sdac[2] sdab[1] sdaa[0]
      11720540160 blocks super 1.2 level 6, 512k chunk, algorithm 2 [6/6] [UUUUUU]
      [>....................]  resync =  0.0% (1279132/2930135040) finish=1438.5min speed=33931K/sec
      bitmap: 22/22 pages [88KB], 65536KB chunk

md127 : inactive md7[2](S) md3[1](S)
      17580548096 blocks super 1.2

md3 : active raid6 sdz[5] sdy[4] sdx[3] sdw[2] sdv[1] sdu[0]
      11720540160 blocks super 1.2 level 6, 512k chunk, algorithm 2 [6/6] [UUUUUU]
      [>....................]  resync =  0.0% (1488528/2930135040) finish=1361.9min speed=35839K/sec
      bitmap: 22/22 pages [88KB], 65536KB chunk

md23 : inactive md2[1](S)
      8790274048 blocks super 1.2

md2 : active raid6 sdr[5] sdq[4] sdp[3] sdo[2] sdn[1] sdm[0]
      11720540160 blocks super 1.2 level 6, 512k chunk, algorithm 2 [6/6] [UUUUUU]
      [>....................]  resync =  0.0% (2165400/2930135040) finish=1032.5min speed=47260K/sec
      bitmap: 22/22 pages [88KB], 65536KB chunk

md1 : active raid6 sdl[5] sdk[4] sdj[3] sdi[2] sdh[1] sdg[0]
      11720540160 blocks super 1.2 level 6, 512k chunk, algorithm 2 [6/6] [UUUUUU]
      [>....................]  resync =  0.9% (28889600/2930135040) finish=610.7min speed=79172K/sec
      bitmap: 22/22 pages [88KB], 65536KB chunk

md0 : active raid6 sdf[5] sde[4] sdd[3] sdc[2] sdb[1] sda[0]
      11720540160 blocks super 1.2 level 6, 512k chunk, algorithm 2 [6/6] [UUUUUU]
      [>....................]  resync =  1.5% (45517312/2930135040) finish=771.3min speed=62328K/sec
      bitmap: 22/22 pages [88KB], 65536KB chunk
```

Commands to creat arrays just in case:

```
mdadm --zero-superblock
sgdisk -Z

mdadm --create /dev/md8 -v --raid-devices=6 --bitmap=internal --level=6 /dev/sda[yz] /dev/sdb[abcd]
```

Apparently 
the system is somehow trying to add newly crated arrays to RAID0 from previous configuration. But where are the data about it about it stored? So i can wipe it clean and create brand new RAID60

```
root@vod0-brn:~# mdadm -D /dev/md23
/dev/md23:
        Version : 1.2
     Raid Level : raid0
  Total Devices : 1
    Persistence : Superblock is persistent

          State : inactive

           Name : vod0-brn:23  (local to host vod0-brn)
           UUID : 2b4555e5:ed4f13ca:9a347c91:23748d47
         Events : 0

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice

       -       9        2        -        /dev/md2

root@vod0-brn:~# mdadm -D /dev/md127
/dev/md127:
        Version : 1.2
     Raid Level : raid0
  Total Devices : 2
    Persistence : Superblock is persistent

          State : inactive

           Name : debian:25
           UUID : f4499ca3:b5c206e8:2bd8afd1:23aaea2c
         Events : 0

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice

       -       9        7        -        /dev/md7
       -       9        3        -        /dev/md3
root@vod0-brn:~# mdadm -D /dev/md126
/dev/md126:
        Version : 1.2
     Raid Level : raid0
  Total Devices : 1
    Persistence : Superblock is persistent

          State : inactive

           Name : debian:26
           UUID : 52be5dac:b730c109:d2f36d64:a98fa836
         Events : 0

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice

       -       9        5        -        /dev/md5
root@vod0-brn:~# mdadm -D /dev/md125
/dev/md125:
        Version : 1.2
     Raid Level : raid0
  Total Devices : 1
    Persistence : Superblock is persistent

          State : inactive

           Name : debian:28
           UUID : 4ea15dcc:1ab164fc:fa2532d1:0b93d0ae
         Events : 0

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice

       -       9        8        -        /dev/md8
root@vod0-brn:~# mdadm -D /dev/md23 
/dev/md23:
        Version : 1.2
     Raid Level : raid0
  Total Devices : 1
    Persistence : Superblock is persistent

          State : inactive

           Name : vod0-brn:23  (local to host vod0-brn)
           UUID : 2b4555e5:ed4f13ca:9a347c91:23748d47
         Events : 0

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice

       -       9        2        -        /dev/md2
```

After i mdadm --stop /dev/md** them, they aren o longer present in /proc/mdstat, but they are still present in the system which i dont like very much. Its just a half-solution

```
root@vod0-brn:~# cat /dev/md 
md/    md0    md1    md125  md126  md127  md2    md23   md29   md3    md4    md5    md6    md7    md8    md9
```

mdadm --examine will still find them, even with different names, what a messs :( :

```
ARRAY /dev/md/23  metadata=1.2 UUID=2b4555e5:ed4f13ca:9a347c91:23748d47 name=vod0-brn:23
ARRAY /dev/md/26  metadata=1.2 UUID=52be5dac:b730c109:d2f36d64:a98fa836 name=debian:26
ARRAY /dev/md/25  metadata=1.2 UUID=f4499ca3:b5c206e8:2bd8afd1:23aaea2c name=debian:25
ARRAY /dev/md/28  metadata=1.2 UUID=4ea15dcc:1ab164fc:fa2532d1:0b93d0ae name=debian:28
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there were MD raid devices created on top of other MD raid devices, which is why once `/dev/md2` is created, the system detects a RAID0 on that device and creates `/dev/md23`.

In this case it would be best to add a line to your `/etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf` file:

```
DEVICE /dev/sd*
```

Now the system should only consider `/dev/sd*` devices when trying to assemble existing MD raid devices.

Comment: Thanks, but i want to buld RAID0 on top of my RAID6 as well, so i wondere where the system read info abou previously existing RAIDS on top of RAIDs so i can just wipe it. Its remembering for some reason only few RAIDs. I wiped disks left and right with dd, wipefs, zerosueprblock, sgdisk....but nothing helped. Still got 3 unwanted arrays assembeled. This time they are named like the old ones md23 md26 and md27. Any idea?

Comment: If you know what MD devices you want to use for your RAID0, add those to the DEVICE line. Otherwise you need to do `mdadm --zerosuperblock` on the assemlbed RAID6 devices.

Comment: i get this `root@vod0-brn:~# mdadm --zero-superblock /dev/md5
mdadm: Couldn't open /dev/md5 for write - not zeroing`
, is it due to assemble in progress? should i wait after assemble is done, than mabye stop it, zero it and start it?

Comment: Might be, although it's usually possible to write to an MD device while syncing is active. Maybe it'll end up zeroing the MD device components itself :( Otherwise you don't have much options left besides completely filling the devices with `dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdxx bs=1024k`...

Comment: i did 'dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdbn bs=1 count=512' but didnt help, that deleted MBR and PT. With sgdisk i deleted GPT, wipefs -a filesystem...still no luck. It would be painfull to dd all 60 3TB disks :( Good i can experiment on this server, but as you said iam running out of solutions

Comment: the `bs=1 count=512` is (a) slow (`count=1 bs=512` does the same and is more efficient) and (b) only good for zeroing the very first sector. The MD superblock is either at the end of the device or at the beginning, with possibly an offset of 4k, see https://raid.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/RAID_superblock_formats#Sub-versions_of_the_version-1_superblock

Comment: Thanks for explanation, i finally found solution - your advice was right i just made noob mistake. Before zero blocking RAID6, it was obviously necessary to stop RAID0 that assembled over it - cause the error message. After I stopped it i was able to zero-block RAID6 it and after cleaning disks with sgdisk and rebooting just in case, only RAID6 will assemble, no more old RAID0 left. Still its strange to me, how random it was.